# Detecting boundaries and resetting circular buffer pointer in both directions

Tags: buffer, microcontroller, 8051, circular-buffer

I am working with an 8051 microcontroller, but my question is more algorithm specific.

I have created a circular buffer in memory for random incoming data from external sources. Suppose the buffer is 32 bytes and I received 34 bytes of data. Yes I'll handle that two bytes are dropped, but if I wanted to read the last 5 bytes then I'll have to somehow wrap around to the end of the buffer again to read more than 2 bytes.

Here's an example in 8051 code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
BUFFER equ 40h     ;our buffer = 40-5Fh (32 bytes)
BUFFERMASK equ 5Fh ;Mask so buffer doesn't go past 32nd byte

initialization:
mov R1,#BUFFER ;R1=our buffer pointer

mov @R1,#xxh ;Add some incoming data 
inc R1
anl R1,#BUFFERMASK

mov @R1,#xxh ;Add some incoming data 
inc R1
anl R1,#BUFFERMASK
...
mov @R1,#xxh ;Add some incoming data 
inc R1
anl R1,#BUFFERMASK

;At this point we filled a large chunk of the buffer with data.
;Lets assume the buffer wrapped around and address is 41h
;and we want to read the data in reverse

mov A,@R1 ;Get last byte at 41h
dec R1
??? R1,??? (anl won't work here :( )

mov A,@R1 ;Get byte at 40h
dec R1
??? R1,??? (anl won't work here :( )

mov A,@R1 ;Get byte at 5Fh (how do we jump with a logic statement?)
dec R1
??? R1,??? (anl won't work here :( )
```

I understand that I could get away with a CJNE (compare and jump if not equal), but the disadvantages with that statement are: 1.) a need for a label for each CJNE, 2.) and the carry flag being modified after execution, and 3.) an extra clock cycle wasted if the boundary is hit.

Is there any way I could pull this off with simple anl/orl (AND or OR) logic? I am willing to change the memory address of the cyclic buffer if that creates an advantage in my situation.

Comment: But a memcpy equivalent takes precious cpu cycles. My chip is an AT89S52 and only has 256 bytes of memory total so memory addresses 100h+ are non-existant.

Comment: and yes old_timer, I tried fixed-base. It works for forward. thats why I used 40h-5Fh in my example.

Comment: but what about if 40h turns to 3Fh? I'd use dec R1, then what logic to make sure 3Fh becomes 5Fh, and anything from 40h to 5Fh is 40h to 5Fh?

Comment: AND then ADD the base, or OR the base depending.  You need a base and offset if you want to limit the range of the circular buffer using a logical operation (AND in this case). Otherwise you have to compare and jump, those are your choices.

Comment: for reverse you have to use base+offset, forward you can in some cases use one register, but not in others   256 bytes starting at 0x1100  (0x11FF+1)&0x11FF != 0x1100.  but 0x1100 + ((offset+1)&0xFF) does work. so does 0x1100 + ((offset-1)&0xFF)

Comment: of course if the base address is zero then both work with simply a mask.